# How to automatically add many variables in a loop-for-count in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I want to use a loop-for-count to loop many different variables to let user input and let CLIPS read the variables.

For example:

Question: "How many dependent you wish to add?"

Answer: 5.

Then the CLIPS should create the variables like:

name1

name2

name3

name4

name5

Here is my code:

```
(printout t "How many dependent you wish to add? (Must have atleast 1): ")
    (bind ?DepNo (read))
    (assert (DepNo ?DepNo))
    (loop-for-count (?DepNo 1 ?DepNo) do 
        (printout t "Name: ")
        (bind $?DepName (explode$ (readline)))
        (assert (DepName $?DepName))
        
    )
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. When placed in the actions of a rule, your code will assert DepName facts. Why do you need to dynamically create variables?

Comment: Hi Gary, reason i want to dynamically create variable for store multiple names, like an array store multiple names in a same array.

Current situation is:
NameA assert into DepName
NameB assert into DepName

When printout DepName, only show me the very last fact which is NameB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a multifield value to hold all of the dependent names:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule get-dependents
   =>
   (printout t "How many dependent you wish to add? (Must have at least 1): ")
   (bind ?DepNo (read))
   (bind ?depNames (create$))
   (loop-for-count ?DepNo 
      (printout t "Name: ")
      (bind ?depNames (create$ ?depNames (readline))))
   (assert (DepNames ?depNames)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule print-names
   (DepNames $?depNames)
   =>
   (printout t "Dependents are: ")
   (foreach ?d ?depNames
      (printout t "   " ?d crlf)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
How many dependent you wish to add? (Must have at least 1): 3
Name: Sally Jones
Name: Fred Jones
Name: David Jones
Dependents are:  
   Sally Jones
   Fred Jones
   David Jones
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (DepNames "Sally Jones" "Fred Jones" "David Jones")
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```